# How can I automatically perform Buffalo Way replacement?

Tags: replacement

[Buffalo Way](https://web.archive.org/web/20210617025753/https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/the-buffalo-way/) is a [common method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffalo-way) for proving inequalities by substituting variables $a_1, \dots, a_n$ in the following manner:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 &\to a_1 \\
a_2 &\to a_1 + x_2 \\
a_3 &\to a_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
  \vdots \\
a_n &\to a_1 +\sum_{i=2}^nx_i
\end{align}
$$
How can I write a program in Mathematica that does this automatically regardless of the number of variables ($n$ in the example above)?

It seems I need some kind of a "rule" to be used with `ReplaceAll`, but I don't know how to generate one (instead of writing it out directly, which is impossible not knowing the number of variables).

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of a system to which you want to apply the substitution, and the desired result, in Mathematica code?

Comment: For example, `bds` is a multi-var polynomial of `a1`, `a2` and so on. I want to substitute the variables like what `/.` does. @MarcoB

Comment: Never heard of the 'Buffalo Way'. Tried looking it up but all I got was a Brilliant.org article which I can't access and just redirects to their front page. Is this like adding slack variables? Could you not just use `FindInstance` or `LinearOptimization` or `Reduce`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `n = 3;k = 0; NestList[# + x[++k] &, a1, n]` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the idea of `Accumulate` as demonstrated by @Ulrich Neumann, but with `Threaded` instead of `Join`

```
Table[a[1], {i, 2, 5}] + Threaded[Accumulate[Table[x[i], {i, 2, 5}]]]
```

**Edit:** thanks to @kglr for spotting this

```
a[1] + Accumulate[Table[x[i], {i, 2, 5}]]
```

Comment: (+1) Your solution using `Threaded` is the fastest, mate! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks. I had no idea about speed. Performance issues I guess :-)

Comment: `a[1] + Accumulate[Table[x[i], {i, 2, 5}]]` gives the same output

Comment: @kglr thanks a lot. edited the answer :-)

Answer (score 10):

Use a replacement rule:

```
R = a[n_] -> a[1] + Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n}];

a[1] /. R
(*    a[1]    *)

a[5] /. R
(*    a[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]    *)
```

Answer (score 10):

What about  `Accumulate`?

```
Join[{a1}, Table[x[i], {i, 2, 5}]] // Accumulate;
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you want a set of rules suitable for using as substitutions in Mathematica, then something like this might give you what you want:

```
Buffalo[a_Symbol, x_Symbol, len_] := Table[a[i + 1] -> a[1] + Total[Array[x, i, 2]], {i, 0, len - 1}]

Buffalo[a, x, 5] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using the same format as @lericr's answer, but using `FoldList`:

```
Buffalo[a_Symbol, x_Symbol, len_] :=
 (
  lhs = Array[a, len];
  rhs = FoldList[Plus, a[1], Array[x, len - 1, 2]];
  Thread[lhs -> rhs]
  )
Buffalo[a, x, 5] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

**Updated**

```
FoldList[#1+x[#2]&, a[1], Range[2,4]]

(* 

 {a[1],
  a[1]+x[2],
  a[1]+x[2]+x[3],
  a[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]} 
*)
```

```
Thread[Array[a,4]->FoldList[#1+x[#2]&, a[1], Range[2,4]]]

(* 
   {a[1]->a[1],
    a[2]->a[1]+x[2],
    a[3]->a[1]+x[2]+x[3],
    a[4]->a[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]} 

*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
Buffalo[a_Symbol, x_Symbol, len__Integer?Positive] := MapApply[Rule,
    Transpose[
            {
                Map[a, Range[1, len]],
                Part[
                    Reap[
                        Do[{Sow[a[1] + Total[Array[x, i, 2]]]},
                                {i, 0, len - 1}
                            ]
                    ],
                    -1, 1
                ]
            }
        ]
   ];

Buffalo[a, x, 5] // TableForm
```

[image]

Another version of @ydd answer using `FoldList`:

```
Buffalo[a_, x_, l_] := Rule @@@ Transpose@{a /@ Range[1, l], 
                       FoldList[#1 + x[#2] &, a[1], Range[2, l]]}
```

Comment: Reap + Sow FTW!!!

Comment: Thanks and happy coding, mate! :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
Accumulate @ Array[If[# == 1, a, x] @ # &, 5]

Accumulate[Array[x, 5]] /. x[1] -> a[1]

Array[x, 5, 1, ReplaceAll[x[1] -> a[1]] @* Accumulate @* List]

g[1] = a[1]; g[i_] := x[i]; Accumulate @ Array[g, 5]
```

all give

> ```
> {a[1], a[1] + x[2], a[1] + x[2] + x[3], a[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4], 
>  a[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]}
> ```